# Unable to access any objects or functions from within the browser console, yet everything works as intended?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am using "classses" with a bunch of static members to keep my very professional code somewhat organized. Like so:

index.html

```
<script type="module" src="client/js/main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
import { UINav, UIDimension } from "./interface.js";
import { Dimension } from "./dimension.js";
import { InputFlex } from "./input.js";
function main() {
    Dimension.init();
    UIDimension.init();
    UINav.init();
    InputFlex.start();
}
```

My question: Why am I getting, for instance, `Uncaught ReferenceError: InputFlex is not defined` when I want to check stuff from inside the browser console, but all methods from the imports all execute as expected? How can I find my beloved "classes" from inside the browser?
I am using TypeScript also but I doubt that matters?
Edit: The files are fetched from a localhost server.

**Edit: There seems to be a general problem in my environment where I cannot even find the *main()* function from inside the browser console.** I am running a deno server. Could this be the root of my funny problem?
I am able to log stuff from inside the js files but not from the browser console where I am told everything is undefined, but evidently those entities exist somewhere, because everything is working as intended.

Edit: @iamimran input.js is literally just this:

```
export class InputFlex {
    static myMember123 = {...};
    static start() {...}
    (...)
}
```

Comment: Error message is self describing "InputFlex" is not defined. Please verify that name in input.js and also upload input.js file so someone can help you out. Thank

Comment: All methods execute and all static members must exist for the methods to execute properly, it also says that even main is not defined, but everything is working. To be perfectly clear: my problem is not execution, but finding everything from inside the browser console and I do not understand the problem there. Thanks.

Comment: Ok but what happens when you set a breakpoint before you use `InputFlex`? Is it missing from `input.js`? Seems it is.

Comment: I do not understand your point at all, it feels like both comments so far are completely ignoring what I have been trying to say. Judging by my experience posting this, it appears my ability to communicate is alarmingly impaired.

Comment: @SimonHackl ... the OP most probably works with an development environment which with any code change always applies/executes a build process which either creates a totally encapsulated module system (of maybe many files) and/or merges all modules into an also encapsulated code of a single file which even might be the more likely option. The OP might have a look into the build processes of the development/production environment. A keyword to additionally look for could be *sourcemap/s*.

Comment: If you are referring to me as the OP, it is literally the vanilla js files being imported exactly like in the snippet above, nothing fancy going on. Now I'm not experienced with using the module type, so I personally suspect it might have something to do with that, but I am still absolutely clueless as to what the cause of this is. It was just curiosity that led me to ask this question, but I was faced with people completely missing the point and acting like they are so sure about the nature of my situation. Just a very sobering experience.

Comment: As you mentioned browser console, I assume you are running a web page. Can you also post your HTML file to show how you load the scripts?

Comment: @RickyMo i happened to just do that, the script is at the end of the <body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `import`s show that you are working with [ECMAScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

One of the main motivations behind using modules is to not pollute the global name space, which means that any variables defined in your modules are private to that module, not global. This is called *encapsulation*.

If you want anything in a module to become a global variable, you explicitly need to "publish" it on the global object:

```js
import { UINav, UIDimension } from "./interface.js";
import { Dimension } from "./dimension.js";
import { InputFlex } from "./input.js";

// to "publish":
Object.assign(globalThis, { UINav, UIDimension, Dimension, InputFlex });
// ...
```

Keep in mind that this is potentially dangerous because the above call to `Object.assign` would effectively overwrite any potentially already existing global variables (one of many reasons why you want to use the global name space as little as possible, preferrably *not at all*).

If your only intention is to "test" stuff in the console this is okay temporarily (!). If you're doing it for debugging purposes, it's be better to outright use your browser's developer tools debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Modules have their own scope. Variables declared inside them are not global.

This is a good thing: Global variables lead to conflicts and make maintenance and debugging harder.

If you want to access them from the developer tools console then you will need to move the console into the scope of the module, e.g. by setting a breakpoint there.